# C# Displaying a image in a form that is non-blocking to the rest of my code

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I know this is a rather broad question, but have a class that has a method to display an image
and would like to use that method in a different piece of code to open up the image, but not have that method call be blocking.

So if I had the following snippet somewhere in a piece of code:

```
ImageClass MyImage = new ImageClass();
MyImage.DisplayImage(@"C:\SomeImage.jpg");
Console.Writeline("This is the line after displaying the image");
```

I would basically want the image to display and then proceed on to the Console Writeline.  Do I have to create a new thread or process to do this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will need to use additional threads.  I'm not as familiar with GDI, but you may need to run the non-UI code in a separate thread so that the UI code can run in the main UI thread.  Something like the following:

```
ImageClass MyImage = new ImageClass();
MyImage.DisplayImage(@"C:\SomeImage.jpg");
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(new delegate(object o) {
    Console.Writeline("This is the line after displaying the image");
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, creating a new thread and calling MyImage.DisplayImage(@"C:\SomeImage.jpg");
in that thread is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

PictureBox.LoadAsync() will load w/o blocking.